# Syntax error unexpected?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: screenshot of the command and the error]
Can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong? Did I type this wrong?

This is the command that I try to execute:

```
/testfor @a[score_keycard_min=1,r=3]
```

This is the error that I get:

> Syntax error: unexpected "score_keycard_min" at "estfor @a[>>score_keycard_min=1<<,r=3]"

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of the bedrock edition (the pocket edition is considered to be the bedrock edition, too) the syntax for scores in the target selector has changed and it is more like the java edition now.

To do what you try to do, you can use this command instead:

```
/testfor @a[scores={keycard=1..},r=3]
```

Comment: I'm currently not able to test it, but the command should work like that.